# Do the caches of all processor's cores are synchronized during Java 8 Stream parallel processing?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, synchronization, java-8, java-stream

If we are working on multi-core processor we need the caches of these cores to be in sync if a task is divided and distributed to the different cores to work on. How do Java 8 Stream library achieve this? Do the caches of all processor's cores are synchronized during Java 8 Stream parallel processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the guarantees of the [Java Memory Model](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4). As long as your program is properly synchronized (via `synchronized`, `Lock`, or other form of synchronization), your shared memory will be visible to all threads.

It's not that the caches will be "synchronized," but they will be reloaded before accessing properly synchronized variables and flushed when writing to properly synchronized variables.

JLS [§17.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.3)

> Within a sequentially consistent execution, there is a total order
>   over all individual actions (such as reads and writes) which is
>   consistent with the order of the program, and each individual action
>   is atomic and is immediately visible to every thread.

---

JLS [§17.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.3)

> It is important to note that neither `Thread.sleep` nor `Thread.yield`
>   have any synchronization semantics. In particular, the compiler does
>   not have to flush writes cached in registers out to shared memory
>   before a call to `Thread.sleep` or `Thread.yield`, nor does the compiler
>   have to reload values cached in registers after a call to `Thread.sleep`
>   or `Thread.yield`.

Comment: Yes you are right but I want to now whats actually happening in Stream parallel processing case as we are not using synchronized, Lock or other form of synchronization here.

Comment: @VineetTyagi The Stream API is synchronizing internally.

Comment: @VineetTyagi  For instance, the [`findXXX` methods](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/FindOps.java#157) use [an `AtomicReference`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/stream/AbstractShortCircuitTask.java#50) to synchronize.